# JQuery change clone inputs to empty

Tags: jquery, clone

I am trying to clone a class that contains inputs and textareas, and turn their values to nothing.

```
var current = $(".item").last();

  current.clone().insertAfter( current );
  current.find('input,textarea').val('');
```

The problem is instead of clearing the cloned objects inputs and textareas, it clears the last class inputs and textareas before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is modifying the `current` objects, not the cloned ones. Try something like this:

```
var current = $(".item").last();

var cloned = current.clone();
cloned.find('input,textarea').val('');
cloned.insertAfter( current );
```