# Reset a Jquery added row blank:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add a new row with Jquery - I am able to do so, except it is cloning the row exactly and not giving me a new blank row.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last')
    $("#invoicetable tbody>tr:last").each(function() {this.reset().val('');}); 
    return false;
});
```

[image: Example of duplicating row]

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery change clone inputs to empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308621/jquery-change-clone-inputs-to-empty)

Comment: Try `$('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last').clone().find('input').val('').end().insertAfter('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last');`

Comment: This fixed it, please change your answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace `this` by `$(this)`.
To apply `reset()` and `val()` you need use a jQuery element and point to form element like so:

```
$('#add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last');
    $("#invoicetable tbody>tr:last").each(function() {
        $(this).find('input, select').reset().val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, still get the same output;


        $('#add').click(function(){
  $('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#invoicetable tbody>tr:last')
  $("#invoicetable tbody>tr:last").each(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Replace return false
      $(this).reset().val('');
  }); 
 });

Comment: Thanks, I went with @gui47's answer - he got it for me in one line.